# Deploy the skill as a web service (not with ngrok to tunnel the localhost)

Tags: java, http, https, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to deploy the skill's service as a web service, not with a lambda function but as an HTTPS endpoint (Alexa needs HTTPS endpoint for request forwarding). The ASK-SDK-JAVA servlet helps to achieve the same but the documentation described about the local usage with TOMCAT and NGROK. I deployed the same `.war` as used in the documentation on Heroku but request is not being forwarded to the endpoint. How can I host the service as an HTTPS endpoint? Can I use `.jar` or only `.war`?

I made the sample HelloWorld program with "SkillServlet" [as shown here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/tree/2.0.x/samples/helloworldservlet).

When I invoke the skill. Alexa throws the following speech output

```
There was a problem communicating with the requested skill.
```

(It's not being able to query the endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not following the rules [as mentioned here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html) by Alexa team. They have a set of rules like verifying Alexa requests, and I think they do this for security and 100% uptime reasons.

I don't know about the `java-sdk,` but I also wanted to deploy my `node-sdk` skill on my custom endpoint, and I found Alexa rules very complicated. So I would suggest you stick with hosting on Lambda.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to manually make the JSON of the response in the format that was readable by Alexa but that testing was just on my local machine. I agree about the request handling on amazon side like timestamp checking and skill id checks. In java ask-sdk-servlet-support takes care of that but in nodejs I don't know if such support exists. I just want to link the ask-sdk-servlet in Java with Spring to host as a custom web service.